# NullPointerException: Passing value from one bean to another using CDI won't work

Tags: jsf, exception, dependency-injection, javabeans, cdi

I use this code in the JSF page

```
<h:outputText value="#{writeBean.t}" />
```

(and I have a beans.xml in WEB-INF folder)

this is the WriteBean where the latter StringBean is injected:

```
package huhu.main.managebean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Default
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class WriteBean implements Serializable {
   /**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

String t;

@Inject StringBean stringbean;


public WriteBean() {
  setT(stringbean.getS());
}

public String getT() {
  return t;
}

public void setT(String t) {
  this.t = t;
}
}
```

and this is the StringBean where the string is set that I want to display on the JSF page:

```
package huhu.main.managebean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Default
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class StringBean implements Serializable {

   /**
* 
*/
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   String s = new String("WORKS!!");

   public StringBean(){

   }

   public String getS() {
     return s;
   }

   public void setS(String s) {
  this.s = s;
  }
}
```

and this is the exception:

```
    HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
root cause

com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:397)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:102)
    org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:115)
    org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:96)
    org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsf.ForwardingELResolver.getValue(ForwardingELResolver.java:46)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:186)
    org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.newInstance(SecureReflections.java:340)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:240)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:87)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$000(ClientProxyProvider.java:43)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:53)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:46)
    com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:102)
    org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:115)
    org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:96)
    org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsf.ForwardingELResolver.getValue(ForwardingELResolver.java:46)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    huhu.main.managebean.WriteBean.<init>(WriteBean.java:25)
    huhu.main.managebean.WriteBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.<init>(WriteBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$16.work(SecureReflections.java:343)
    org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:173)
    org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.newInstance(SecureReflections.java:340)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:240)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:87)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$000(ClientProxyProvider.java:43)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:53)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:46)
    com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:102)
    org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:115)
    org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:96)
    org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsf.ForwardingELResolver.getValue(ForwardingELResolver.java:46)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final logs.

JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final
```

Comment: I tried to access data, I was writing in the constructor - won't work! Just found the answer!

Comment: Please don't yell SOLVED in titles. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Just post it as a normal answer to the question and when the time allows it, mark it as accepted. This way the question appears as "answered" in the listing, which equals to yelling SOLVED in those old fashioned discussion forums.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for the hint! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my fault was simply: You can't call an injected property in the constructor because it would mean trying to access a property that hasn't been set yet.
Now I just emptied the WriteBean contructor and used the line of code in a new method writer():

```
public String writer(){
    setT(stringbean.getS());
    return t;
}
```

that one I called on the jsf page:

```
<h:outputText value="#{writeBean.writer()}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to create that method (replacing your constructor) :

```java
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    setT(stringbean.getS());
}
```

from `javax.annotation.PostConstruct` and it will be called just after CDI created your bean.